# Rails 5.1 Redirect to current_user.subdomain after_sign_in_path_for with apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, apartment-gem

Can't seem to get this to work. I am using the Apartment Gem and Devise and trying to redirect after sign_in to the users subdomain.  When user first registers they are transferred to their subdomain; I just can't seem to get it to work once logged out and signing in again.

**application_controller.rb**
This doesn't work

```
...
protected
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  return root_url(subdomain: current_user.subdomain)
end
...
```

but this will transfer me to the current_user id (http://3.lvh.me:3000)

```
...
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  return root_url(subdomain: current_user)
end
...
```

so I know I am on the right track. I've tried more variations than I can remember to try and have it transfer to (http://subdomain.lvh.me:3000)

I'm not sure what code exactly to include here, but we'll start with my controller create code that will redirect the user to the subdomain after registration--hopefully this will spark some ideas.

**accounts_controller.rb**

```
...
def create
  @account = Account.new(account_params)
  if @account.save
    @account.create_schema
    sign_in(@account.owner)
    flash[:notice] = 'Your account has been created.'
    redirect_to root_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = 'Sorry, your account could not be created.'
    render :new
  end
end
...
```

Comment: So I had a similar problem where I have projects subdomains instead of users. I used a snippet you have provided and it works just fine for me: `root_url(subdomain: resource.project.subdomain)`. However, my projects model has a column named `subdomain` storing the subdomain.